# I need to access the data in a JSON file using Python and extract a certain part of the file

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON file. It basically holds the latitude and longitude of some of the counties in the US. I need to extract only those items where STATE ID is 48 (thats for Texas). I tried a code but it only got the file serialized

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GEO_ID": "0500000US01001", "STATE": "01", "COUNTY": "001", "NAME": "Autauga", "LSAD": "County", "CENSUSAREA": 594.436000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -86.496774, 32.344437 ], [ -86.717897, 32.402814 ], [ -86.814912, 32.340803 ], [ -86.890581, 32.502974 ], [ -86.917595, 32.664169 ], [ -86.713390, 32.661732 ], [ -86.714219, 32.705694 ], [ -86.413116, 32.707386 ], [ -86.411172, 32.409937 ], [ -86.496774, 32.344437 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GEO_ID": "0500000US01009", "STATE": "01", "COUNTY": "009", "NAME": "Blount", "LSAD": "County", "CENSUSAREA": 644.776000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -86.577799, 33.765316 ], [ -86.759144, 33.840617 ], [ -86.953664, 33.815297 ], [ -86.954305, 33.844862 ], [ -86.962960, 33.844865 ], [ -86.963358, 33.858221 ], [ -86.924387, 33.909222 ], [ -86.793914, 33.952059 ], [ -86.685365, 34.059140 ], [ -86.692061, 34.092654 ], [ -86.599632, 34.119914 ], [ -86.514881, 34.254370 ], [ -86.453020, 34.259317 ], [ -86.303516, 34.099073 ], [ -86.332723, 33.986109 ], [ -86.370152, 33.939770 ], [ -86.325622, 33.940147 ], [ -86.377532, 33.861706 ], [ -86.577528, 33.801977 ], [ -86.577799, 33.765316 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GEO_ID": "0500000US01017", "STATE": "01", "COUNTY": "017", "NAME": "Chambers", "LSAD": "County", "CENSUSAREA": 596.531000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -85.184131, 32.870525 ], [ -85.123421, 32.772248 ], [ -85.132040, 32.764211 ], [ -85.136776, 32.746512 ], [ -85.285043, 32.730731 ], [ -85.593151, 32.728530 ], [ -85.593177, 33.107340 ], [ -85.232378, 33.108077 ], [ -85.223261, 33.062580 ], [ -85.221868, 33.055538 ], [ -85.184131, 32.870525 ] ] ] } }
```

```
import json

obj  = json.load(open("test.json"))
result = []


for i in range(len(obj)):
    result.append(i)

open("updated-file5.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
)
```

Comment: `json.dump` instead of `json.dumps`

Comment: What all data u need?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Thanks for that correction Devesh

Comment: @SiddharthDas I need to extract the rows where STATE ID is 48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going. You will get all items with STATE '48' as a list.

```py
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json', 'r'))

res = []

for feature in data['features']:
        if feature['properties']['STATE'] == '48':
                res.append(feature)

print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shafi for the response, I still see the rows other than STATE ID 48 though. I was wondering if there is a way to remove rest of the columns with condition like 
 if feature['properties']['STATE'] !=48 ,  I tried but I get an error using this condition

Comment: I got it now, thanks a lot @Shafi. Currently its just printing on the console. I was looking to redirect the output to a different file serialized in json format. Is there a way to do it too? Sorry I am a beginner, I tried the dumps function but it takes an object as a Parameter, and we need to pass the result of the res.append(). So it failed eventually

Comment: Yes you can definitely do that. You can follow [this](https://pastebin.com/jiLhsUNs) . Let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: thanks @Shafi, that worked too :) Do you suggest any article or blog to learn more about operating on JSON by Python? I am working on a project where I need to use Python and JSON a lot

Comment: You can learn about JSON architecture in [json.org](https://www.json.org/). And basic knowledge of python data types (specially Dictionary [for json]) will help you how you can access and manipulate json. [This](https://realpython.com/python-json/) is really a big and good introduction to work with JSON in python. Good luck.